# Spring Data Redis Error handling with Repository and Cache Configurer

Tags: error-handling, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

Can I use Spring Data Redis @Repositories, and a CachingConfigurer to implement error handling? For instance -

```
  @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new RedisCacheError();
    }
```

Using the CacheConfigurer above along with the repository as defined below, note the use of CrudRepository operations.

```
@Repository
public interface ObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<object, String>
```

I notice that CrudRepository has operations such as save, wondering if that is doing a redis.add() in the background? And basically whether or not the ErrorHandler see below, will actually catch errors on the save operation.

```
public class RedisCacheError implements CacheErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception,
                                    Cache cache, Object key) {

        log.info("caught error in here: " + exception );
    }
    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache,
                                    Object key, Object value) {
        log.info("caught error in here: " + exception );
    }
    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache,
                                      Object key) {
        //Do something on error while Evict cache
    }
    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception,Cache cache){
        //Do something on error while clearing cache
    }
}
```